# is there an non-constant analytic complex function that receives only real values ?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to find something like $f(z) = |z|$ (complex function that get's only real values)
the problem here is that $f(z)$ is not analytic.

Comment: You want to find an analytic function with only real values ?

Comment: yes...(but non-constant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the open image theorem, nonconstant analytic functions have an open image, so if $f$ is analytic and only takes real values, its image is included in $\mathbb{R}$, so can't be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$. Therefore $f$ is constant.

Cauchy-Riemann equations can also lead to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

If $f=u+iv$ with $v=0$, by C-R equations:
$$u_x=v_y=0,$$
$$u_y=-v_x=0,$$
So $u$ is...